# How to set Project property value using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to set property in Project level, with my groovy code I can set a property in TestCase level. How can do the same to set property in Project level

Here is my code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
slurperresponse.id.toString()
log.info (slurperresponse.id.toString())
property_name = 'a'
def idProperty = setupTestCase.getProperty(property_name).toString()
setupTestCase.setPropertyValue('a',slurperresponse.a.toString())
```

Here I'm setting the TestCase property "a" from the response of a TestStepName.
I'm using Soapui.

Thank you

Comment: is this soapui? or what are all those object?  if not please provide a complete example.

Comment: yes it's in Soapui, i forgot to mention

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a `project` property in SOAPUI using `groovy` with the follow code:

`testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("yourProp", yourValue )`

Using your code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
slurperresponse.id.toString()
log.info (slurperresponse.id.toString())
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("a",slurperresponse.a.toString())
```

Hope this helps,